# What layout should I use for my app? Lint error?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-tablelayout, android-lint

This is my first app/project ever in android, I'm learning on the fly. I have a warning in lint "youramounts.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance" I know the logic behind the matter just not how to correct it. How do i correct this error? Should i have a different layout other than the linear layout?

I have read several post's on list view and grid view but I am not understanding how to apply them to my app. The image shown is how i want the app to look. I have started to experiment with both list and grid views. I currently replaced the first 2 table rows with grid views just to see what happens, I'm clueless at this point, so I have deleted the grid views and reverted back to table row's. But here is the coding for the layout and the table row's setup, I have 11 table row's and a button that are not shown in the coding ! Thanks for any input in advance!

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotineText"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/e_juice_nicotine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Percent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/vg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Percent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mg" />
</TableRow>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzJxM.png

Comment: you could use a listview

Comment: Check this link out. It should help put you on the right track with regards to a listview: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom
As for a better understanding with layouts please refer to:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/

Comment: Should I stick with a Linear Layout or going with something like a relative layout?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to help you
just paste in your XML layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tbl1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotineText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="e_juice_nicotine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PG"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%"

        android:layout_gravity="center" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VG" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mg" />


</TableRow>

<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotineText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="e_juice_target_nicotine" />

   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mg" />


</TableRow>

<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotineText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="e_juice_quality_to_make" />

   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ml" />


</TableRow>


<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotineText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="water_vodka_pga" />

   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tbl2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EjuiceNicotineText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flavor1" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PG"

        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" % " />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" VG " />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mg" />

     </TableRow>

</TableLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Should i add a table layout to each table row or a single table layout for all of my table rows?

Comment: just go through the code i have given. first parent layout is linear layout and than add two table layouts.